# How do I move a camera around a tiledmap in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the following code for rendering a TiledMap and moving around a Texture representing the player on top of it and the camera is setup to follow the texture around.

However, when I try to move the player which in turn moves the camera, it seems like the tilemap moves as well resulting in the player not moving at all. Here's a gif showing the problem: [Video](https://i.imgur.com/RJdimlZ.gif)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I would appreciate if anyone could help me out.

```
package com.worldgen.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.worldgen.map.WorldMap;

public class WorldGenGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private static final int MAP_WIDTH = 512;
    private static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 512;
    private static final int TILE_SIZE = 16;
    public final static float VP_WIDTH = 32;
    public final static float VP_HEIGHT = 18;

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    WorldMap worldMap;
    private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    private Texture playerTexture;
    private Rectangle player;
    
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        playerTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        player = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, VP_WIDTH, VP_HEIGHT);

        worldMap = new WorldMap(MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(worldMap.getMap(), 1f/TILE_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1, true);
        // Update
        float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        updateCamera(deltaTime);
        updatePlayer(deltaTime);

        //Draw map
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        //Draw player
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(playerTexture, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
        batch.end();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        worldMap.dispose();
        playerTexture.dispose();
    }

    private void updatePlayer(float deltaTime) {
        float movementAmount = 4 * deltaTime;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
            player.x -= movementAmount;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
            player.x += movementAmount;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) {
            player.y += movementAmount;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) {
            player.y -= movementAmount;
        }
    }

    private void updateCamera(float deltaTime) {
        camera.position.set(player.getX(), player.getY(), 0);
        camera.update();
    }
}
```

I suspect the camera position update is where the problem lies because if I comment out the camera update code, I can move around the player on the tilemap. Result: [Video](https://i.imgur.com/ZkEQcUo.gif)

```
    private void updateCamera(float deltaTime) {
//      camera.position.set(player.getX(), player.getY(), 0);
        camera.update();
    }
```

Comment: I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863861/what-are-the-use-cases-for-the-tiledmap-class), I managed to "fix" it by changing the layer's offset each frame.