# What are the use cases for the TiledMap class?

Tags: libgdx

### **Old title: How do I prevent Tiles from moving with the camera? TiledMapRenderer**

I have a world made up of tiles, an OrtographicCamera which follows the player and a ExtendViewport that manages the camera. I'm using TiledMap and OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer to render the world.

```java
public GameScreen() {
        this.extendViewport = new ExtendViewport(playerFOVWidth_mt, playerFOVHeight_mt);
        this.tiledMap = new TiledMap();
        this.mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, Constants.PX_TO_MT_SCALAR, game.batch);
}
```

This is how I render the world

```java
mapRenderer.setView(camera);
mapRenderer.render();
```

The cell at (0,0) appears at the bottom left of the screen and when I move the player, [all the tiles move with it](https://imgur.com/a/tQyi0xM).

I managed to get around this by calling the TiledMapRenderer's [setView](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapRenderer.java) overload that allows me to pass explicit values for the viewbounds.

```java
mapRenderer.setView(camera.combined, -worldWidth_mt/2, -worldHeight_mt/2, worldWidth_mt, worldHeight_mt);
```

But this causes tremendous amounts of lag, because the entire world gets rendered each frame. Is there a way to prevent the tiles from moving with the player and at the same time only render those that are on screen?

**EDIT:**
I managed to hack around this problem by changing the layer's offset as a function of the camera's position on each frame:

```java
tiledMap.getLayers().get(LayerId.WORLD.value).setOffsetX(Drop.mtToPx(-camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth/2 - worldWidth_mt/2));
tiledMap.getLayers().get(LayerId.WORLD.value).setOffsetY(Drop.mtToPx(camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2 + worldHeight_mt/2));
        
mapRenderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) camera);
mapRenderer.render();
```

This feels inherently wrong though, and I'm most likely misusing the TiledMap class. What are the use cases for the TiledMap class? Is there a better way to do this?